# Redirect http to https for only www root and not subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a website to https. I used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have `www.example.com.au` and these redirected fine; however, I also have `mobile.example.com.au` which i don't want to redirect. How can I redirect one without the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another condition to allow this rule for main domain only:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```